# Calculus - $\frac{dy}{d x}$ using partial derivatives

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

I am revising for a calculus exam I have on Monday. One of the past paper questions on partial derivatives is given below:

Let $T(x,y) = \tan(xy^2) + 3y - 2xy$

**i) Find the first order partial derivatives of $T$ with respect to $x$ and $y$.** 
I did this and got:

$$\frac{\partial T(x,y)}{\partial x} = \sec^2(xy^2)y^2 - 2y$$
$$\frac{\partial T(x,y)}{\partial y} = \sec^2(xy^2)2yx + 3 - 2x$$

**ii) Using the above calculate $\frac{dy}{d x}$:**
Now I am familiar with the product and chain rules for partial differentiation but because this is not a composition of functions, drawing the usual variable dependence diagram and summing up the products of those variables using this diagram doesn't seem to make any sense.

My question is therefore: How do I calculate $\frac{dy}{d x}$ from two partial derivatives?

I am sorry that I do not know LaTeX. Also, if you can, please make didactic concessions. I am a mere undergraduate and have only been studying calculus for two and a half months.

**Update: ** This question was asked in the exam. I got my calculus exam results a week ago and passed with distinction. I know I got this question right. :) Thank you all!

Comment: $y$ and $x$ are independent variables -- $dy/dx$ is not defined. Is this the entire problem?

Comment: With the usual interpretation of $dy/dx$ the second question does not makes sense except if $y$ is a function of $x$. An equation like $T(x,y)=$constant defines implicitly $y$ as function of $x$ just supposing a bit more: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem.

Comment: Yes, I am absolutely certain of this; I have posted the question word for word. The fact that x and y are independent variables is what makes me wonder whether the question is ill-posed.

Comment: As is, yes, the question does not make sense.

Comment: In this case I would assume that $T(X,y)=$constant and use the Implicit Function Theorem... It's the only thing that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using chain rule in multivariable calculus .... $dy/dx$ = $-f_x/f_y$

Comment: I have seen this used before! Could you maybe explain or give a link explaining how this chain rule works?

Comment: This is correct but can it be related to the implicit factor theorem or is there a proof I can read; I hate just memorizing formulas.

Comment: @GoofyBall .This can be proved using chain rule for multivariable calculus . in fact this is one of its application . u can see its proof under that in any calc tetbook .

Comment: You helped me pass my exam by providing the correct answer. For this great deed, I accept your answer. Do not hesitate to call upon GoofyBall should the need arise. God speed, gentlesir!